# Performance issue with c3p0 cache object:

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I want to share a weird example. On production our application is throwing OOM exception, we took a heap dump and started to analyze that later we found problem with com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.PerConnectionMaxOnlyStatementCache instance. The size of this object is about 50% of heap size. The application is running with billions of users and server goes down again and again.

This application is running on tomcat, where the tomcat connector allows 300 max concurrent requests and following are the c3p0 configurations.

```
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize=2
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize=150
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=0
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection=50
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads=6
```

From heap monitoring tool we are getting the following message

One instance of "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.PerConnectionMaxOnlyStatementCache" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x82f1c58" occupies 72 970 824 (57,75%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.PerConnectionMaxOnlyStatementCache" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x82f1c58"

Please please advise:-
What can be reason this instance taking such huge memory?
Are we running with right c3p0 configuration?
What are the recommended configurations for a heavy loaded application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said that you are using Tomcat. Why are you then using your own C3P0 instead of Tomcat's connection pooling?

Comment: try setting these parameters  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />  
  <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />

Answer (score 2):

You have set maxStatementsPerConnection=50 and maxPoolSize=150. That implies that the statement cache may have as many as 7500 open Statements at any one time, including the memory footprint of whatever resources your driver associates with Statements. You are basically asking c3p0 to use a whole lot of memory, on the theory that the cost of memory is low compared to the performance cost of preparing a Statement.

First, that might not be true at all, in which case Statement caching is a loser in general, and you should just not use it. You should benchmark your app with both maxStatements and maxStatementsPerConnection set to zero to test whether you are actually getting a benefit from Statement caching, if you haven't already. For drivers that do cache a lot of parsing and preparation in PreparedStatement objects, Statement caching can be a big help. But you face a trade-off between the memory footprint of the cache and the performance benefit of having pre-cached Statements. It's pretty clear that, even if Statement caching is helpful to your performance, you've exceeded the point where the benefits exceed the costs.

How many of those 150 prepared statements in your app are frequently used? Can you make that number smaller, preferably much smaller, expecting that more rarely used Statements will drop out of the cache and good riddance to them? Alternatively, you can leave that number alone, but combine maxStatementsPerConnection with a global maxStatements setting (set to something less than the implicit 7500 that you currently are using). If you combine maxStatementsPerConnection and maxStatements, each Connection will be permitted to have up to maxStatementsPerConnection while the pool is small, but as the pool gets large and memory footprint becomes a hazard, the global Statement limit will cause less-recently-used Statements to start dropping out of the cache to preserve memory.

I hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you gave **maxIdleTime=0**.

Setting the maxIdleTime to a non-zero value permits C3P0 to remove Connections from the pool and freeing up database resources.

> This will never happen when maxIdleTime is set to 0

.

So I believe that none of your connections are removing out from pool.
That is why it is been going huge in heap size.

For more reference [click here](http://javatech.org/2007/11/c3p0-connectionpool-configuration-rules-of-thumb/).

Answer (score -1):

Try [BoneCP](http://www.jolbox.com/) for a high performance connection pool, it solves many performance oriented problems of c3p0 and Apache DBCP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But unfortunately we cannot change the the application to use BoneCP, application is live at too many clients. 
We need to find a way around this. The tomcat setting are as follows    
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="500" 
minSpareThreads="50" 
maxSpareThreads="1000"
enableLookups="false" 
redirectPort="8443" 
acceptCount="150"
connectionTimeout="20000" 
disableUploadTimeout="true"